# Concatenation of IEnumerable collections C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 results of a Linq query, with which i want to do do some string operations and concatenate.

Result 1 which is the names of enabled checkboxes from group1, obtained by

```
var selectedCarPosts = grpBox1MCar.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
.Where(c => c.Checked).OrderBy(c => c.Name).Select(c => c.Name);
```

which yields Result 1:

```
NearMainGate
NearMP5WestGate
```

Result 2 which is the names of enabled checkboxes from group2, obtainedby

```
var selectedDtTypeCars = gbDataTypeMCars.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
.Where(c => c.Checked).OrderBy(c => c.Name).Select(c => c.Name);
```

which yields Result2:

```
WindDir
WindVel
```

**From both results would like to get a concatenated list as follows: (Result3)**

```
C.NearMainGate
C.NearMP5WestGate
C.WindDirNearMainGate
C.WindDirNearMP5WestGate
C.WindVelNearMainGate
C.WindVelNearMP5WestGate
```

These form columns in a dynamic sql query later.

I have the following code to accomplish this step by step:

```
var s1 = selectedCarPosts.Select(s => "C." + s); //the first 2 items in Result3
//Now to get the rest, by inserting Result2 string in each of the first 2 items of Result3
IEnumerable<string> selCarPostsArrWithC = new string[]{};
IEnumerable<string> s2 = new string[]{};
foreach (var type in selectedDtTypeCars)
{
   selCarPostsArrWithC = s1.Select(s => s.Insert(2, type));//C.WindDirNearMainGate C.WindDirNearMP5WestGate in FIRST iteration and so on
   s2 = s2.Concat(selCarPostsArrWithC);// as soon as the SECOND iteration starts, the previous s2 list is overwritten with the subsequent result in selCarPostsArrWithC 
 }
```

The problem here is that during code debugging, I noticed, that as soon as I tap F10 key just after the foreach line, before actually reaching the foreach block, the the previous values in **s2** is overwritten with the subsequent result in selCarPostsArrWithC already. Explained below

For the first iteration s2 has result.

```
[0] "C.WindDirNearMainGate"
[1] "C.WindDirNearMP5WestGate"
```

At the beginning of second iteration before entering inside the foreach block

s2 already resets to new values with **WindVel** some how:

```
[0] "C.WindVelNearMainGate"
[1] "C.WindVelNearMP5WestGate"
```

Please could any one assist what am I doing wrong? How can i accomplish Result3 in bold, for the IEnumerable list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have a list of prefixes, and a list of suffixes. (Note: I skimmed your code, and I couldn't find where you got the `C.` that was appended to each of the values.)

For every prefix, you need a suffix.

This is the use of `SelectMany()`

I simplified your code, because you gave quite a bit of code. But here's what I came up with:

```
    var location = new[]
    {
      "NearMainGate", 
      "NearMP5WestGate"
    };

    var modifier = new[]
    {
      "WindDir", 
      "WindVel"
    };

    var lambdaResult = modifier.SelectMany(s => location.Select(l => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "C.", s, l)));

    var queryResult =
        from m in modifier
        from l in location
        select string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "C.", m, l);
```

Note that there's two solutions: a linq query syntax, and linq lambda syntax.

In this situation, I think the query syntax is cleaner and easier to read, but to each their own.

And here's a fiddle with proof of functionality: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z61RsI

Comment: Hi Cameron! wow That was awesome. Thank you very much.(an upvote requires 15 points. have just 7 now. as soon I reach 15 I'll do it) Now I realize how new I am to LINQ .. need to learn more LINQ syntax in addition to mastering C#. (you might have understood already I am quite a new bee) ;-) both your lambda and query results works like a charm. Could you suggest good books, resources for LINQ and Winforms programming in C#? sorry offtopic.

Comment: @Nish There are **tons** of resources. I personally learn best from looking at working code. [MSDN's Linq Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) are great.If you want code samples, the Microsoft has [101 LInq Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) to look at.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Select` doesn't do anything important when you call it, it merely sets things up so that the requested work will be performed later as desired.

So when you write

```
selCarPostsArrWithC = s1.Select(s => s.Insert(2, type));
```

this doesn't call `string.Insert` yet. `string.Insert` is only called when you (or your debugger) later starts iterating over `selCarPostsArrWithC`.

Normally, that doesn't matter, except for performance if you iterate over the enumerable multiple times. However, here, because `string.Insert` is called later than you expect, the arguments that you pass to it are *also* evaluated later than you expect. You only have a single `type` variable, and that variable already holds the next value by the time it gets read.

In general, you can either solve this by creating a new variable per iteration, that captures the value of `type` as seen during that iteration:

```
foreach (var type in selectedDtTypeCars)
{
  var type_ = type;
  selCarPostsArrWithC = s1.Select(s => s.Insert(2, type_));
  s2 = s2.Concat(selCarPostsArrWithC);
}
```

(Nowadays, C# already does this behind the scenes for `foreach`, but you may need to write it out like this if using an older compiler.)

Or, alternatively, perform all of the evaluations directly inside the loop body:

```
foreach (var type in selectedDtTypeCars)
{
  selCarPostsArrWithC = s1.Select(s => s.Insert(2, type)).ToList();
  s2 = s2.Concat(selCarPostsArrWithC);
}
```

Although in that case, it would be better to just make `s2` a `List<string>`, and call its `AddRange` method.

Comment: Hi hvd. Thanks for the infos.. I tried the solution form Cameron.. and it worked. But Thanks still. your comment answers why my code did not work. lot of LINQ stuff to learn :-).